# Need PHP Mysql Suggested Categories name from Title posted

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php        
$colname_subselect = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $colname_subselect = $_POST['title'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_donedeal, $donedeal);
$query_subselect = sprintf("SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE subcatename LIKE %s");
?>
```

I'm trying to show suggested categories from the title which is posted from previous page to categories.php page, example, In previous Page Field Name Title Contain Text :

`## I Want My Motor Car To Sell##`

Once submit it will go to categories.php which query i written above. Using LIKE function i able to get suggested categories when i write only one keyword like i written car in title field of previous page so in categories.php page suggested categories will show which contain car keyword.

No what i want is that when i posted complete ad post title like

`## I Want My Motor Car To Sell##`

how can i show the suggested categories like above title contain motor and car keyword, so it should show in categories.php categories contain car and motor keyword ? Got ME ?

I m using innodb so MATCH method will not work, any other prefer method would be much appreciated please...

Comment: Souns like you are looking for [soundex](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?164318-using-SOUNDEX-in-MySQL-to-do-a-search). [Another example](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/201153/How-to-use-LIKE-with-Soundex-in-Mysql). Also splitting the title to words would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $colname_subselect = "-1";
if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
$colname_subselect = $_POST['title'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_donedeal, $donedeal);
$queryString = trim(implode('or subcatename  like ',explode(' ',$colname_subselect )), 'or');
$query_subselect = sprintf("SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE " . $queryString  );
```

Please Note that you might have to escape string for stopping sql injection.

Comment: I would highly recommend this nice library for MySQL - http://www.meekro.com - easy to setup/use and takes care of SQL injection also